# Как сгруппировать информацию из таблицы?

Tags: php

Допустим, имеется такая таблица **Categories**:

```
Type | SubType | Name
4      0         Новости 
4      1         Новости Авто
4      2         Новости Мира
```

Поле `Type` содержит **ID** главной категории. В данном случае везде категория - Новости.
Поле **SubType** определяет под-категорию.

Пытаюсь вывести информацию в виде:

---

**Новости**

- Новости Авто
- Новости мира

Проблема в том, что в таблице **Categories** нет `SubType` > 0. Т-е подкатегория `Новости Авто, Новости` Мира не содержится в таблице, нужно делать дополнительный запрос в PHP на выбор под-категории.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подзапросиком

SELECT name FROM category
WHERE SubType IN (SELECT SubCategoryID
FROM SubCategory
WHERE Type= '2');

это как пример, загуглите если че